# Where can I sell large quantities of guns the easiest?

Tags: starfield

I have a ship full of guns that I have "collected", but do not need. They are either duplicates of ones I already have, or worse versions. I could dump them off my ship or onto the ground to get rid of them, but I could always use for credits, so would prefer to sell them all. Where can I sell my dozens of weapons the quickest/easiest?

Answer (score 10):

There are quite a number of different cities with multiple vendors, however I have found Neon seems to have the largest cluster that is easily accessible without too much running. If you land at Neon Core, there are 6 vendors that I have found that will buy weapons:

- Newill's Goods - 5000 credits
- Mining League - 5000 credits
- Neon Tactical - 12500 credits
- Trade Authority - 11000 credits
- Sieghart's Outfitters - 5000 credits
- Emporium - 3500 credits

Between these vendors, you can sell up to 42000 credits worth of guns, then simply find a bench and wait for 48 local hours and repeat. If you don't wish to have any loading screens at all, Trade Authority, Neon Tactical, and Newill's Goods can all be visited without going through a door with a loading screen.

Note: Once you get some bank built up, you can buy resources or other things you might need from the vendors prior to selling the weapons to them to get back the money you spent. It doesn't necessarily increase your credit count directly, but it essentially allows you to trade unneeded weapons for resources you might need. It also speeds up the process of offloading guns if you have dozens or even hundreds of them.

Comment: Rest on Venus which is 100:1 UT time dilation to speed up the 48 hours

Comment: Definitely agree with buying stuff from the vendors: I usually grab all the ammo I'm using first then sell what I can, then possibly any resources, etc.

Comment: Great list!  I have found that Trade Authority in most locations will have 11K or so in credit, and are in most locations.

Comment: @Neon1024, you should make that an answer.

Comment: @BillThePlatypus It does not answer the question asked, so no, it is better as a comment.